# android save object in firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database

I created sign in app and I am using with firebase database.
But I have a problem when I am trying to save object in the database. Although when I am trying to save simple string or simple `HashMap` object everything working.

I got an error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found a conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined on android.content.ContextWrapper)

Here is my code:

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText userName;
    EditText password;
    Button signInbtn;
    DatabaseReference url;
    Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        url = database.getInstance().getReference();
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        signInbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInBtn);
        signInbtn.setOnClickListener(signObject);

    }  
    View.OnClickListener signObject = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            User user = new User("Moshe","1234");
            users.put("101",user);
            DatabaseReference userUrl = url.child("Users");
            userUrl.setValue(users);
            System.out.println(users);
        }
    };
```

**Class User:**

```
public class User extends Application{

    public static String password;
    public static String name ;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String name,String password){
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public  String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public  void setName(String name) {
        User.name = name;
    }

    public  String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public  void setPassword(String password) {
        User.password = password;
    }
}
```

I added permmision.Internet to the manifest. I read a lot of question about this subject and specially about Firebase, but I did not find any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase can only read and write fairly basic Java objects (so-called Plain Old Java Objects or POJOs) to the database. By extending your `User` class from `Application`, you're violating those rules.

The solution is to make your `User` class completely standalone:

```
public class User {
    ...
```

Comment: i did what you say now the app not crushing while it is compiling but still it is not saving the data

Comment: That could be for many reasons and really would be a different question. That said: I'd start by listening for security problems in `setValue()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201612090709222522846