# Firebase Database Exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the class where i intend to read a Location type data item from firebase database and store it in a Location type Object. I even tried to store the datasnapshot in an object of the class that had a Location type argument in the constructor, i got the same error saying :

" com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class android.location.Location is missing a constructor with no arguments"

```
package com.example.aadi.sarthi_;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ActiveNotifications extends Fragment{
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "NOTIFICATION MSG";
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String user_mac;
    public List<notifyListRowItem> result;
    public UserAdapter userAdapter;
private     DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private     DatabaseReference eventRef = reference.child("Events");

    // Create a Intent send by the notification
    public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( context, ActiveNotifications.class );
        intent.putExtra( NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg );
        return intent;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_active_notifications, container, false);
        getMac();
        result = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.notification_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager rlm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rlm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rlm);
        /*
        createNotifyListRowItem();*/
        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(result);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        updateList();
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void updateList(){
        final DatabaseReference locationRef = reference.child(String.valueOf(user_mac)).child("location");
        final Location userLoc = null;
        final Location eventLoc = null;

        locationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    Location location = dataSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);
                userLoc.set(location);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
       eventRef.limitToFirst(2).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                eventRef.push().child("location");
                Location location = dataSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);
                eventLoc.set(location);

                if(eventLoc.distanceTo(userLoc)<=1000) {
                    result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(notifyListRowItem.class));

                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.w("asd", "In onChildChanged");
                notifyListRowItem notifyListRowItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(notifyListRowItem.class);
                int index = getItemIndex(notifyListRowItem);
                result.set(index,notifyListRowItem);
                userAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.w("In ", "OnchildRemoved");
                notifyListRowItem model = dataSnapshot.getValue(notifyListRowItem.class);
                int index = getItemIndex(model);
                result.remove(index);
                userAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.w("IN", "onChildMoved");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w("IN", "onChildCancelled");
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    private int getItemIndex(notifyListRowItem item){
        int index = -1;

        for (int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            if(result.get(i).key.equals(item.key)){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
    protected void getMac(){
        GettingMac gettingMac = new GettingMac(getActivity());
        user_mac = gettingMac.Mac();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add some context to your code example here. It looks to me though that you need to read the documentation on the Location class.

Comment: `Class android.location.Location is missing a constructor with no arguments`. Doesn't look like you can use that class in your Firebase database, then

Comment: Is that cool @ToothlessRebel

Comment: I got the same problem, while I tried to store the datasnapshot in an object that had a Location type variable in the arguments.@Too

Comment: You cannot use arbitrary Java/Android classes when interacting with the Firebase Database. It doesn't know how to deal with them and those classes often don't follow the rules that Firebase has (public fields/getters, no-argument public constructor). So you'll have to create your own class that captures the relevant information of a location. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045025/android-save-object-in-firebase/41047756#41047756

Comment: @sahiljain I submitted an edit to clean up some of your formatting but yeah. Just FYI code can be formatted by beginning the line with four spaces, not `~~~~` or ````` like in other systems.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel that was just for spotting the error location quickly through log

Comment: then how do I read Location type object saved in my Firebase Database @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: As said: you need to create your own POJO class for writing to and reading from the database.

Comment: My question ain't the same at all, i am able to save every other data type but Location.  @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The reason you can't read or write `android.location.Location` is because it doesn't implement a public default constructor. As explained in the linked question, you cannot serialize arbitrary Android classes to the Firebase Database. You will have to implement your own Java class that contains just the information you want to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an empty constructor for your Location class.

```
public Location () {}
```

Comment: Did that already. But didn't help.

Comment: There is also a class in Android called "Location". See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html. Make sure you imported the correct class. Will be better if you rename your class to something else.

Comment: No, I don't have a class named "Location", I edited the Location class imported that you're refering to

Comment: Can you post your class here as well? How did you edited the Location class?

Comment: Okay @tingyik90

Comment: I added the empty argument constructor in the android.location.Location class @tingyik90

Answer (score 0):

You should need to add a constructor of your Location Class.

```
 public Location() {

}
```

Comment: Did that already. Didn't work

Comment: @Override
protected Location parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot;
}
try this

Comment: Try what? @ArslanJaved