# Read "Location" object from firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location

I am able to read and retrieve String, double, custom objects from firebase database but am not able to read Location object specifically.

How do I read Location object from firebase database?

[FirebaseDatabase snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2lnm.png)

I want to read the data in the location field from the database. I have already written into the database

Comment: The Firebase Database client can only serialize simple types (as you said) and POJO classes that consists of simple types and getters and setters. Most built-in Android classes don't adhere to these rules, so cannot directly be written to/read from the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410174/firebase-database-error-found-conflicting-getters-for-name-isaccessibilityfoc/42418502#42418502 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045025/android-save-object-in-firebase

Comment: What should I do then exactly?@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You will need to create you own Java class that contains just the information that you want to store in the database. If you're having problems with that, share the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To read complex objects from firebase, you need either to **have a JSON parser** to extract location information.
 Another simple idea is to **create a simple class encapsulating necessary location information** with setters and gettors i.e. *latitude* and *longitude*. 
 Further simpler method is to **add these attributes to the user class** you are using to handle users data. I have used the latter approach to save location info in a project I am working on.